# Flutter StreamController returning duplicate data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my widgets setup in the following hierarchy to pass data between the two tabs

```
DataShareWidget
 TabBarView
   InputManagment
   InfiniteListView
```

The DataShareWidget extends InheritedWidget and contains the ShareData class which has a StreamController to send and receive data.

but on the receive side (InfiniteListView tab) am getting duplicate data.

I've printing out the raw data from InputManagment before entering the stream, but there does not appear to be any duplicate data, so it must be something with the stream.

Here the relevant code from the main file

```
class ShareData {
  final StreamController _streamController = StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream get stream => _streamController.stream;
  Sink get sink => _streamController.sink;
}

class DataShareWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  final ShareData data;
  DataShareWidget({
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
  }) :assert(child != null),
      data = ShareData(),
      super(key: key, child: child);
  static ShareData of (BuildContext context) => (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(DataShareWidget) as DataShareWidget).data;
  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(DataShareWidget old) => false;
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("MyApp"),
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: Tabs,
          controller: _tabController,
        ),
      ),
      body: DataShareWidget(
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            InputManagment(),
            InfiniteListView(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the data management file i have this line of code to add data

```
DataShareWidget.of(context).sink.add(inputData);
```

And here is the code for InfiniteListView

```
class _InfiniteScrollListViewState extends State<InfiniteScrollListView> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<InfiniteScrollListView>{
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  var _listViewData = new List();

  _dataFormat(data){
    var time = DateFormat('kk:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());
    var timeStampedData = time.toString() + "| " + data;
    setState(() {_listViewData.add(timeStampedData); });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DataShareWidget.of(context).stream.listen((data) => _dataFormat(data));
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _listViewData.length,
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: AutoSizeText(_listViewData[index], maxLines: 2),
            dense: true,
          );
        },
      );
  }
}
```

EDIT: As per @jamesdlin suggestion i've refactored the code using StreamBuilder, and that appears to have solved the issue, here is the updated code below.

```
_dataFormat(data){
    var time = DateFormat('kk:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());
    var timeStampedData = time.toString() + "| " + data;
    _listViewData.add(timeStampedData);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //_scrollToBottom();
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: DataShareWidget.of(context).stream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasError){ return Text(snapshot.error);}
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          _dataFormat(snapshot.data);
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _listViewData.length,
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: AutoSizeText(_listViewData[index], maxLines: 2),
                dense: true,
              );
            },
          );
        }
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `listen` on the `Stream` every time `_InfiniteScrollListViewState.build` is called.  That will result in your callback being invoked multiple times.  You should listen to the `Stream` only once.

You also perhaps should consider using a [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) widget instead.